# C programming--why gets() not taking input?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int choice;
   char sl[10];
   char phn[10];
   printf("Enter choice: ");
   scanf("%d",&choice);
   switch(choice)
   {
   case 1:
       printf("\nEnter Student Details: \n\n");
       printf("\nEnter serial number: ");
       gets(sl);
       printf("Roll number: ");
       gets(phn);
   default:
      break;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

C PROGRAMMING:

I used 2 gets() function here. second one is working but first one is not working. why?? how to make it work?

N.B: I want to take "sl" and "phn" variable as char type and I want to use gets() to take input.
please someone help....

Comment: [DO NOT use `gets()`, it is dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917). use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Comment: Think a little: What is the key you use to end the input for the number you input for `scanf`? Hint: The `Enter` key will also be put into the input buffer as a newline character.

Comment: `gets` is dangerous and deprecated (and removed from C11 standard). Use `fgets` or perhaps [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fgets for all input. scanf usually leaves a newline in the input stream that will cause problems for fgets. Parse the input for an integer with sscanf and check the return to make sure an integer was input.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int choice;
    int result = 0;
    char sl[10];
    char phn[10];
    char input[256];
    do {
        printf("Enter choice: ");
        if ( ( fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin))) {
            result = sscanf( input, "%d", &choice);
            if ( result == 0) {
                printf ( "try again\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem getting input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    } while ( result != 1);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("\nEnter Student Details: \n\n");
            printf("\nEnter serial number: ");
            if ( ( fgets ( sl, sizeof sl, stdin)) == NULL) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "problem getting serial number\n");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Roll number: ");
            if ( ( fgets ( phn, sizeof phn, stdin)) == NULL) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "problem getting roll number\n");
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use `gets()`. It offers no protections against a buffer overflow vulnerability (that is, you cannot tell it how big the buffer you pass to it is, so it cannot prevent a user from entering a line larger than the buffer and clobbering memory).

`fgets()` is safe because you can guarantee you never overflow the input string buffer by passing in the buffer size (which includes room for the NULL.)

The most important difference is that `fgets()` knows how big the string
is and `gets()` does not. That means it is nearly impossible to write
safe code using `gets()` so don't do it.

in there use `fgets()` instead of `gets()`